# Circles problem, show that C-(A+B) can get very close to 1

Tags: geometry

Draw a circle; it has area $1$. Inscribe a triangle in it. Let $A, B, C$ denote the non-triangle regions of the circle, with $C$ being the largest.

**A.** Show that $C-(A+B)$ can get very close to $1$.

**B.** Find the minimum value of $C-(A+B)$. Hint: It is negative!

(If I can figure out B with the explanation of A, then you don't need to do B as well, but I don't know)

Help me please!

Comment: Suppose the triangle has all sides much smaller than 1 – then $C$ is almost the whole circle and $A$ and $B$ are close to $0$...

Answer (score 0):

**A.** I don't sure I understand "can get very close to 1". You can just make your triangle smaller as $A+B$ will become smaller and $C$ will become bigger so that $C-A-B$ is bigger and get very close to 1.

**B.** The answer is when the triangle is equilateral (calculate it yourself). To prove this, let start on a chord $AB$ in this circle. Make it horizontal and choose any point on the circumference above. Let us choose $P$ first. Then, if $Q$ is a point lower than $P$, area of $AQB$ will be smaller than $APB$. 
At this point you should see that as $Q$ goes lower, the area which isn't in the triangle will get bigger.

It's so easy to show that the chord length respected to $C$ must be at least the side of equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle. Then, I think it's very easy for you to end the proof;).